# How to change the time format in Extent report 3.0.2 for c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, extent

I am trying to change format of time displayed in extent report for C#.
Currently its displaying as "07/09/2017 10:59:58". so is it possible to change these format in any other format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible in version 3 of ExtentReports.NET.  However, you can open an [enhancement request](https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-csharp) for future versions.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have raised enhancement request for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it like this .

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourObject.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string s = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried above method to change time format in extent report. But it didn't work.